# How to GROUP BY + Merge values of a column together within a SFMC data extention

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, sql

here is the problem I am facing. I essentially need to group and then take the values of any unique user, and combine them and delimit them out by " | " into the result for each product.

[image]

Any idea how this can be done with Salesforce Marketing Cloud's version of 2005 TSQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a CROSS APPLY, STUFF and FOR XML.  I believe these all work in SFMC.

```sql
select * FROM [UserModels]
```

```sql
SELECT distinct
  um.userId
, STUFF(x.models,1,1,'') models
FROM [UserModels] AS um
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT '|' + rtrim(um0.model)
    FROM [UserModels] AS um0
    WHERE um0.userid = um.userid
    FOR XML PATH('') 
) x ( models )
```

Output:

```
UserID  Model
5       wood      
5       metal     
6       sand      
7       plastic
```

```
userId  models
5       wood|metal
6       sand
7       plastic
```

Comment: Adam, you sir, are a jenius! Thanks so much. I've learned a great deal in this past year from your posts & from the AMPscript Guide book. Thanks again for your awesome help!